# Python ProcessExecutorPool cannot pickle local object

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I have a library that is heuristic and CPU bound that I'm trying to call from a service that is trying to leverage asyncio. To maintain concurrency among CPU bound work loads I'm trying to delegate work to a ProcessPoolExecutor in asyncio. I have setup my code as such:

```
from ExternalPackageimport SomeCpuBoundAlgorithmInAConsumedPackage

executors = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)

async def run_algorithm(request):
   algo = SomeCpuBoundAlgorithmInAConsumedPackage(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   result = await loop.run_in_executor(executors, algo.run, param1, param2)

class Service:
   async def receive_request(request):
     //parse request and dispatch up to 100 calls to algorithm
     await asyncio.wait_for(run_algorithm, timeout=10)
```

This gives the error

```
Can't pickle local object 'run_algorithm.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

From my understanding its because Processes rely on pickling your data and for this it has to be a top level function. While run_algorithm is a top level function, `SomeCpuBoundAlgorithmInAConsumedPackage` is not and cannot be a top level function. What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: If you can import it from an external module, then it is a top-module function. From the error, it seems like you are trying to return a lambda from the target function, which cannot be pickled.

Comment: I'm not returning a lambda, but the algorithm is using a lambda expression to instantiate something within which could be the culprit

Comment: then perhaps it would be better if you included more information about this target function

Comment: Please present the exact line of code that causes the exception.  When Python pickles a function it only pickles the *name* of the function, and relies upon the import mechanism to access the function's code after unpickling.  That's why functions to be pickled have to be top-level: so they can be imported.  I think the error is because you are trying to pickle the coroutine object that results from a *call* to `run_algorithm`.  That could not be pickled and would be a "local object" as the error message says.  Another reason to show us the line of code that raises the error.